# How to identify the misconfiguration on this yaml file for Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, configuration, yaml, aws-cloudformation

Good afternoon,

I am having some issues with a CloudFormation given to me for an assignment on AWS.
The CloudFormation script creates a stack on AWS, but it does not let me display the website.
I have checked all the initial settings:

- Set HTTP allowance for Inbound/Outbound in both LoadBalancer & APP Security Groups
- Autoassign IP settings on both Public Subnets

I am a total newbie on AWS so I need some help with this misconfiguration.
I am attaching the yaml file here:

```
Description: |

  AWS CloudFormation Assignment: Find the misconfiguration on the script and make
  the website run (DNS Hostname)

Parameters:


  CandidateName:
    Description: 'Please input your first and last name:'
    Type: String
    MaxLength: '50'
    MinLength: '3'
    ConstraintDescription: Please input your full name.

Resources:


    SAVPC:
      Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
      Properties:
        CidrBlock: 10.0.0.0/16
        InstanceTenancy: default
        EnableDnsSupport: 'true'
        EnableDnsHostnames: 'true'
        Tags:
          - Key: environment
            Value: sa-assignment
          - Key: Name
            Value: !Join ['-', [SAVPC, !Ref 'CandidateName']]

    PublicSubnetA:
      Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
      Properties:
        CidrBlock: 10.0.0.0/24
        AvailabilityZone: eu-west-1a
        MapPublicIpOnLaunch: 'True'
        VpcId: !Ref 'SAVPC'
        Tags:
          - Key: environment
            Value: sa-assignment
          - Key: Name
            Value: !Join ['-', [PublicSubnetA, !Ref 'CandidateName']]

    PublicSubnetB:
      Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
      Properties:
        CidrBlock: 10.0.1.0/24
        AvailabilityZone: eu-west-1b
        MapPublicIpOnLaunch: 'True'
        VpcId: !Ref 'SAVPC'
        Tags:
          - Key: environment
            Value: sa-assignment
          - Key: Name
            Value: !Join ['-', [PublicSubnetB, !Ref 'CandidateName']]

    PrivateSubnetA:
      Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
      Properties:
        CidrBlock: 10.0.2.0/24
        AvailabilityZone: eu-west-1a
        VpcId: !Ref 'SAVPC'
        Tags:
          - Key: environment
            Value: sa-assignment
          - Key: Name
            Value: !Join ['-', [PrivateSubnetA, !Ref 'CandidateName']]

    PrivateSubnetB:
      Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
      Properties:
        CidrBlock: 10.0.3.0/24
        AvailabilityZone: eu-west-1b
        VpcId: !Ref 'SAVPC'
        Tags:
          - Key: environment
            Value: sa-assignment
          - Key: Name
            Value: !Join ['-', [PrivateSubnetB, !Ref 'CandidateName']]

    SAIGW:
      Type: AWS::EC2::InternetGateway
      Properties:
        Tags:
          - Key: environment
            Value: sa-assignment
          - Key: Name
            Value: !Join ['-', [IGW, !Ref 'CandidateName']]

    SANetworkACL:
      Type: AWS::EC2::NetworkAcl
      Properties:
        VpcId: !Ref 'SAVPC'
        Tags:
          - Key: environment
            Value: sa-assignment
          - Key: Name
            Value: !Join ['-', [NACL, !Ref 'CandidateName']]

    SARoutePublic:
      Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
      Properties:
        VpcId: !Ref 'SAVPC'
        Tags:
          - Key: environment
            Value: sa-assignment
          - Key: Name
            Value: !Join ['-', [PublicRoute, !Ref 'CandidateName']]

    SARoutePrivate:
      Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
      Properties:
        VpcId: !Ref 'SAVPC'
        Tags:
          - Key: environment
            Value: sa-assignment
          - Key: Name
            Value: !Join ['-', [PrivateRoute, !Ref 'CandidateName']]

    SAInstance1:
      Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
      Properties:
        DisableApiTermination: 'false'
        InstanceInitiatedShutdownBehavior: stop
        ImageId: ami-047bb4163c506cd98
        InstanceType: t2.micro
        Monitoring: 'false'
        UserData: IyEvYmluL2Jhc2gNCnl1bSB1cGRhdGUgLXkNCnl1bSBpbnN0YWxsIC15IGh0dHBkMjQNCnNlcnZpY2UgaHR0cGQgc3RhcnQNCmNoa2NvbmZpZyBodHRwZCBvbg0KZ3JvdXBhZGQgd3d3DQp1c2VybW9kIC1hIC1HIHd3dyBlYzItdXNlcg0KY2hvd24gLVIgcm9vdDp3d3cgL3Zhci93d3cNCmNobW9kIDI3NzUgL3Zhci93d3cNCmZpbmQgL3Zhci93d3cgLXR5cGUgZCAtZXhlYyBjaG1vZCAyNzc1IHt9ICsNCmZpbmQgL3Zhci93d3cgLXR5cGUgZiAtZXhlYyBjaG1vZCAwNjY0IHt9ICsNCmVjaG8gJzxodG1sPjxoZWFkPjx0aXRsZT5TdWNjZXNzITwvdGl0bGU+PC9oZWFkPjxib2R5PjxpZnJhbWUgd2lkdGg9IjU2MCIgaGVpZ2h0PSIzMTUiIHNyYz0iaHR0cHM6Ly93d3cueW91dHViZS5jb20vZW1iZWQvSnMyMXhLTUZkd3ciIGZyYW1lYm9yZGVyPSIwIiBhbGxvd2Z1bGxzY3JlZW4+PC9pZnJhbWU+PC9ib2R5PjwvaHRtbD4nID4gL3Zhci93d3cvaHRtbC9kZW1vLmh0bWw=
        Tags:
          - Key: environment
            Value: sa-assignment
          - Key: Name
            Value: !Join ['-', [Instance1, !Ref 'CandidateName']]
        NetworkInterfaces:
        - AssociatePublicIpAddress: 'true'
          DeleteOnTermination: 'true'
          Description: Primary network interface
          DeviceIndex: 0
          SubnetId: !Ref 'PublicSubnetA'
          GroupSet: [!Ref 'SASGapp']
          
    SAelb:
      Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer
      Properties:
        Subnets: [!Ref 'PublicSubnetB']
        Instances: [!Ref 'SAInstance1']
        SecurityGroups: [!Ref 'SASGELB']
        Listeners:
        - LoadBalancerPort: '80'
          InstancePort: '80'
          Protocol: HTTP
        HealthCheck:
          HealthyThreshold: '2'
          Interval: '15'
          Target: TCP:443
          Timeout: '5'
          UnhealthyThreshold: '2'
        Tags:
          - Key: environment
            Value: sa-assignment
          - Key: Name
            Value: !Join ['-', [ELB, !Ref 'CandidateName']]

    SASGELB:
      Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
      Properties:
        GroupDescription: SA Assignment - ELB security group
        VpcId: !Ref 'SAVPC'
        Tags:
          - Key: environment
            Value: sa-assignment
          - Key: Name
            Value: ELBSecurityGroup

    SASGapp:
      Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
      Properties:
        GroupDescription: SA Assignment - App server security group
        VpcId: !Ref 'SAVPC'
        Tags:
          - Key: environment
            Value: sa-assignment
          - Key: Name
            Value: AppServerSecurityGroup

    SANACLEntry1:
      Type: AWS::EC2::NetworkAclEntry
      Properties:
        CidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
        Egress: 'true'
        Protocol: '-1'
        RuleAction: allow
        RuleNumber: '100'
        NetworkAclId: !Ref 'SANetworkACL'

    SANACLEntry2:
      Type: AWS::EC2::NetworkAclEntry
      Properties:
        CidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
        Protocol: '-1'
        RuleAction: allow
        RuleNumber: '100'
        NetworkAclId: !Ref 'SANetworkACL'

    subnetacl1:
      Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetNetworkAclAssociation
      Properties:
        NetworkAclId: !Ref 'SANetworkACL'
        SubnetId: !Ref 'PublicSubnetA'

    subnetacl2:
      Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetNetworkAclAssociation
      Properties:
        NetworkAclId: !Ref 'SANetworkACL'
        SubnetId: !Ref 'PublicSubnetB'

    subnetacl3:
      Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetNetworkAclAssociation
      Properties:
        NetworkAclId: !Ref 'SANetworkACL'
        SubnetId: !Ref 'PrivateSubnetA'

    subnetacl4:
      Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetNetworkAclAssociation
      Properties:
        NetworkAclId: !Ref 'SANetworkACL'
        SubnetId: !Ref 'PrivateSubnetB'

    SAIGWAttachment:
      Type: AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment
      Properties:
        VpcId: !Ref 'SAVPC'
        InternetGatewayId: !Ref 'SAIGW'

    subnetRoutePublicA:
      Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
      Properties:
        RouteTableId: !Ref 'SARoutePublic'
        SubnetId: !Ref 'PublicSubnetA'

    subnetRoutePublicB:
      Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
      Properties:
        RouteTableId: !Ref 'SARoutePublic'
        SubnetId: !Ref 'PublicSubnetB'

    subnetRoutePrivateA:
      Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
      Properties:
        RouteTableId: !Ref 'SARoutePrivate'
        SubnetId: !Ref 'PrivateSubnetA'

    subnetRoutePrivateB:
      Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
      Properties:
        RouteTableId: !Ref 'SARoutePrivate'
        SubnetId: !Ref 'PrivateSubnetB'

    publicroute:
      Type: AWS::EC2::Route
      Properties:
        DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
        RouteTableId: !Ref 'SARoutePublic'
        GatewayId: !Ref 'SAIGW'
      DependsOn: SAIGW

    
Outputs:


  LoadBalancerDNSName:
    Description: The DNSName of the load balancer
    Value: !GetAtt SAelb.DNSName
```

Any input would be helpful.
Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: I should be able to access the website under the Outputs tab of the CloudFormation in AWS console but when I open it, it shows me I can't reach the website.

Answer (score 0):

You are using healthchecks `Target: TCP:443`, while I don't see in your UserData anything related to port 443 nor SSL. Seems to me you want to use port 80.

There still could be many other issues in your template, but the **port is definitely wrong**.

Also, there is a **mismatch between subnets and AZs** set for your instance and CLB.